# Rails doesn't recognize my new class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm so confused as to why this isn't working. So inside of a controller, I have something that looks like this

```
#controllers/report_controller.rb
def new
  test = GenerateReport.generate(data)
end
```

and then I have a model that looks like this:

```
#models/generate_report.rb
class GenerateReport < ActiveRecord:Base
   def self.generate(data)
      # some code
   end
end
```

When my controller hits the "new" action, it actually works. However, if I renamed GenerateReport to GenerateReportX and change the function in the controller accordingly, restart the rails app, it doesn't recognize GenerateReportX. I don't get why this is the case? I'm renaming everything that says GenerateReport in the whole rails app and restarting the app completely.

My actual problem was that a new model that I've created is almost an exact mimick of the one that works fine (without me renaming it), and its class isn't being recognized.

I've tried adding this `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to `application.rb` and that doesn't fix anything.

Any suggestions and possibly clarification on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class is named `GenerateReportX` it has to live in `models/generate_report_x.rb`

Comment: What about HMTLtoXML class? I have a model file called html_to_xml and it's not working. Is it a formatting issue?

Comment: this is not the best way to name a Rails class. If you don't want to fight "convention over configuration" you'd better name it `HtmlToXml`